# Conditions does not match result

Tags: javascript, html

I have a condition that identifies if 2 inputted values are equal or one is greater than the other. Sometimes it works and sometimes it displays a wrong result.

```js
function identify() {
  var num1, num2;

  num1 = document.getElementById("num1").value;
  num2 = document.getElementById("num2").value;

  if (num1 == num2) {
    document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = num1 + " and " + num2 + " are equal";
  } else if (num1 > num2) {
    document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = num1 + " is greater than " + num2;
  } else if (num2 > num1) {
    document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = num2 + " is greater than " + num1;
  }
}
```

```html
<h2>Enter first number: </h2>
<input type="number" id="num1" />

<h2>Enter second number: </h2>
<input type="number" id="num2" />

<button onclick="identify()">Identify</button>

<p id="answer"></p>
```

Comment: _sometimes_ , can you write an example that function doesn't work?

Comment: `.value` will always return a string and therefor compare them as strings. Parse them as numbers before you compare them.

Comment: Well it prints out that the lower value is greater than the higher value

Comment: Simone asked for an actual example, so actual values for `num1` and `num2`...

Comment: i did my self, if you put 2 into first and 12 for example in second bug will compare, the answer is your suggest too

Comment: You should pass the value of the input to `parseInt(value, 10)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bug compare because `.value` return `string` and not `int`, `parseInt` resolve your problem

```js
function identify(){
    var num1,num2;

         num1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("num1").value);
         num2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("num2").value);
        

        if(num1 == num2){
            document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = num1 +" and " + num2 + " are equal";
        }

        else if(num1 > num2){
            document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = num1 +" is greater than " + num2;
        }

        else if(num1 < num2){
            document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = num2 +" is greater than " + num1;
        }
}
```

```html
<h2>Enter first number: </h2>
    <input type = "number" id="num1" />

<h2>Enter second number: </h2>
    <input type = "number" id="num2" />

<button onclick = "identify()">Identify</button>

<p id ="answer"></p>
```

Comment: Have you test it?

Answer (score 0):

As stated by the answers above `parseInt` will indeed solve your problem because you were comparing strings.
When comparing strings with comparison operators the algorithm compares each character one by one starting from the left until it finds the first character which is less or greater. The less or greater is determined by the unicode value (superset of ASCII) of those characters which is a **number**.

Example:

Unicode values of 3,4,5 are 51,52,53 in decimal.

**204** is greater than **20330** because the 3rd character has a higher unicode value

**20530** is greater than **204** because the 3rd character has now a higher value